# unable to convert json to dataframe, polars panicked

Tags: rust, serde, rust-polars

```
use reqwest::blocking::get;
use polars::prelude::*;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::io::Cursor;


#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct StockZhAHist {
    date: String,
    open: f64,
    close: f64,
    high: f64,
    low: f64,
    volume: f64,
    turnover: f64,
    amplitude: f64,
    change_rate: f64,
    change_amount: f64,
    turnover_rate: f64,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/public/stock_zh_a_hist";
    let response = get(url)?.text()?;
    // println!("{}", response);
    // deserialize response with serde
    let stock_zh_a_hist: Vec<StockZhAHist> = serde_json::from_str(&response)?;
    // convert to polars dataframe
    println!("{:?}", stock_zh_a_hist);
    let df = JsonReader::new(Cursor::new(response))
        .infer_schema_len(Some(1000))
        .finish()?;
    println!("{:?}", df);
    Ok(())
}
```

i have written a script that retrieves raw data from my server and i was able to print out the JSON 'stock_zh_a_hist'. but somehow when i tried to print out the dataframe converted from this JSON, the programme panicked and returned :

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Arrow datatype Struct([Field { name:
> "date", data_type: LargeUtf8, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }, Field
> { name: "open", data_type: Float64, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} },
> Field { name: "close", data_type: Float64, is_nullable: true,
> metadata: {} }, Field { name: "high", data_type: Float64, is_nullable:
> true, metadata: {} }, Field { name: "low", data_type: Float64,
> is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }, Field { name: "volume", data_type:
> Int64, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }, Field { name: "turnover",
> data_type: Float64, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }, Field { name:
> "amplitude", data_type: Float64, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} },
> Field { name: "change_rate", data_type: Float64, is_nullable: true,
> metadata: {} }, Field { name: "change_amount", data_type: Float64,
> is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }, Field { name: "turnover_rate",
> data_type: Float64, is_nullable: true, metadata: {} }]) not supported
> by Polars. You probably need to activate that data-type feature.',
> /home/arthur/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/polars-core-0.30.0/src/datatypes/field.rs:158:19.

i also read source code there which reads:

```
 #[cfg(feature = "dtype-decimal")]
            ArrowDataType::Decimal(precision, scale) => DataType::Decimal(Some(*precision), Some(*scale)),
            dt => panic!("Arrow datatype {dt:?} not supported by Polars. You probably need to activate that data-type feature."),
```

i am assuming polars is having some problem reading the json with correct datatypes, but how can i solve it?

**update** 1:
i have added the feature dtype-decimal  in cargo.toml but  the same error persists.

**update** 2:
the content of stock_zh_a_hist is as follows:

```
[StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-16T00:00:00.000", open: 16.86, close: 16.86, high: 16.86, low: 16.86, volume: 62442.0, turnover: 105277000.0, amplitude: 0.0, change_rate: -10.22, change_amount: -1.92, turnover_rate: 0.87 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-17T00:00:00.000", open: 15.17, close: 15.17, high: 16.79, low: 15.17, volume: 463675.0, turnover: 718902016.0, amplitude: 9.61, change_rate: -10.02, change_amount: -1.69, turnover_rate: 6.49 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-18T00:00:00.000", open: 15.28, close: 16.69, high: 16.69, low: 15.18, volume: 445380.0, turnover: 719400000.0, amplitude: 9.95, change_rate: 10.02, change_amount: 1.52, turnover_rate: 6.24 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-19T00:00:00.000", open: 17.01, close: 16.4, high: 17.9, low: 15.99, volume: 572946.0, turnover: 970124992.0, amplitude: 11.44, change_rate: -1.74, change_amount: -0.29, turnover_rate: 8.03 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-20T00:00:00.000", open: 16.19, close: 16.39, high: 16.68, low: 15.9, volume: 277758.0, turnover: 451471008.0, amplitude: 4.76, change_rate: -0.06, change_amount: -0.01, turnover_rate: 3.89 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-23T00:00:00.000", open: 16.58, close: 16.57, high: 16.89, low: 16.4, volume: 155369.0, turnover: 258260992.0, amplitude: 2.99, change_rate: 1.1, change_amount: 0.18, turnover_rate: 2.18 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-24T00:00:00.000", open: 16.58, close: 15.95, high: 16.73, low: 15.93, volume: 153168.0, turnover: 249324000.0, amplitude: 4.83, change_rate: -3.74, change_amount: -0.62, turnover_rate: 2.15 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-25T00:00:00.000", open: 16.1, close: 16.47, high: 16.7, low: 15.86, volume: 175391.0, turnover: 285567008.0, amplitude: 5.27, change_rate: 3.26, change_amount: 0.52, turnover_rate: 2.46 },
StockZhAHist { date: "1996-12-26T00:00:00.000", open: 16.68, close: 16.47, high: 16.78, low: 16.3, volume: 51516.0, turnover: 85214000.0, amplitude: 2.91, change_rate: 0.0, change_amount: 0.0, turnover_rate: 0.72 }...]
```

Comment: And have you actually done what the error message suggests?

Comment: activating the data-type feature in polars declaration in cargo.toml? i am not entirely sure if polars has such a feature but will try when i get home in an hour.

Comment: The feature is called `dtype-decimal` (that's what the source code it linked you to shows).

Comment: this is strange. i've added the feature on, and cargo build again, but the error persists and the compiler returns the same panic message.

Comment: You'll need to share a sample json file you're trying to parse, otherwise this is impossible to debug.

Comment: As an aside, why do you infer the schema at all? You seem to already know it, you're deserializing it into a `StockZhAHist` successfully after all.

Comment: yes you are right, i deleted that infer_schema_len line already, it was redundant. also i have added  the output of stock_zh_a_hist above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug — this issue goes away if you enable feature `dtype-struct`, but you definitely shouldn't have to in order to read from json.

As a workaround, even without `dtype-struct`, you can get this to work by converting your data to JSON Lines.

```rust
use polars::prelude::{JsonReader, SerReader};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::io::Cursor;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct StockZhAHist {
    date: String,
    open: f64,
    close: f64,
    high: f64,
    low: f64,
    volume: f64,
    turnover: f64,
    amplitude: f64,
    change_rate: f64,
    change_amount: f64,
    turnover_rate: f64,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let data = vec![
        StockZhAHist {
            date: "1996-12-16T00:00:00.000".into(),
            open: 16.86,
            close: 16.86,
            high: 16.86,
            low: 16.86,
            volume: 62442.0,
            turnover: 105277000.0,
            amplitude: 0.0,
            change_rate: -10.22,
            change_amount: -1.92,
            turnover_rate: 0.87,
        },
        StockZhAHist {
            date: "1996-12-17T00:00:00.000".into(),
            open: 15.17,
            close: 15.17,
            high: 16.79,
            low: 15.17,
            volume: 463675.0,
            turnover: 718902016.0,
            amplitude: 9.61,
            change_rate: -10.02,
            change_amount: -1.69,
            turnover_rate: 6.49,
        },
        StockZhAHist {
            date: "1996-12-18T00:00:00.000".into(),
            open: 15.28,
            close: 16.69,
            high: 16.69,
            low: 15.18,
            volume: 445380.0,
            turnover: 719400000.0,
            amplitude: 9.95,
            change_rate: 10.02,
            change_amount: 1.52,
            turnover_rate: 6.24,
        },
    ];
    // JSON Lines data
    let response = data
        .into_iter()
        .map(|d| serde_json::to_string(&d))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?
        .join("\n");
    println!("{}", response);
    // convert to polars dataframe
    let df = JsonReader::new(Cursor::new(response))
        .infer_schema_len(Some(1000))
        .with_json_format(polars::prelude::JsonFormat::JsonLines)
        .finish()?;
    println!("{:?}", df);
    Ok(())
}
```

```
{"date":"1996-12-16T00:00:00.000","open":16.86,"close":16.86,"high":16.86,"low":16.86,"volume":62442.0,"turnover":105277000.0,"amplitude":0.0,"change_rate":-10.22,"change_amount":-1.92,"turnover_rate":0.87}
{"date":"1996-12-17T00:00:00.000","open":15.17,"close":15.17,"high":16.79,"low":15.17,"volume":463675.0,"turnover":718902016.0,"amplitude":9.61,"change_rate":-10.02,"change_amount":-1.69,"turnover_rate":6.49}
{"date":"1996-12-18T00:00:00.000","open":15.28,"close":16.69,"high":16.69,"low":15.18,"volume":445380.0,"turnover":719400000.0,"amplitude":9.95,"change_rate":10.02,"change_amount":1.52,"turnover_rate":6.24}
[/Users/ben/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/polars-io-0.30.0/src/ndjson/core.rs:162] &data_type = Struct(
    [
        Field {
            name: "date",
            data_type: LargeUtf8,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "open",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "close",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "high",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "low",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "volume",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "turnover",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "amplitude",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "change_rate",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "change_amount",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
        Field {
            name: "turnover_rate",
            data_type: Float64,
            is_nullable: true,
            metadata: {},
        },
    ],
)
shape: (3, 11)
┌─────────────────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───┬───────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────┐
│ date                    ┆ open  ┆ close ┆ high  ┆ … ┆ amplitude ┆ change_rate ┆ change_amount ┆ turnover_rate │
│ ---                     ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---           │
│ str                     ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆   ┆ f64       ┆ f64         ┆ f64           ┆ f64           │
╞═════════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══╪═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1996-12-16T00:00:00.000 ┆ 16.86 ┆ 16.86 ┆ 16.86 ┆ … ┆ 0.0       ┆ -10.22      ┆ -1.92         ┆ 0.87          │
│ 1996-12-17T00:00:00.000 ┆ 15.17 ┆ 15.17 ┆ 16.79 ┆ … ┆ 9.61      ┆ -10.02      ┆ -1.69         ┆ 6.49          │
│ 1996-12-18T00:00:00.000 ┆ 15.28 ┆ 16.69 ┆ 16.69 ┆ … ┆ 9.95      ┆ 10.02       ┆ 1.52          ┆ 6.24          │
└─────────────────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───┴───────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks for the reply mate. i acctivated dtype-struct and all is good and working now.

Comment: also may i ask which way is less expensive? read from json or the workaround?

Comment: @ArthurZhang the workaround is still JSON, but JSON Lines instead of a JSON array. I'd naively assume JSON Lines is cheaper because it's meant to be streamed -- an entire array shouldn't ever be held in memory. But you'd have to profile to be sure.